# Filter SELECT box from previous SELECT box PHP - SQL Server

Tags: php, sql, sql-server-2008

I have a couple of SELECT boxes that are pulling from the database, how can I get the option that is selected in SELECT box 1 to filter the SQL in the SELECT box 2?

EG SELECT 1 - Make (Audi, BMW) SELECT 2 - Model (A1,A3, 1 Series, 3 Series)

I want to show that if I pick Audi from SELECT 1 that it will use Audi to fill the WHERE clause in my SQL to filter for the SELECT 2

```
<label>Manufacturer</label>
<select class="select2_category form-control" data-placeholder="Choose a Category" tabindex="1" id="make" name="make" >
    <option value=""></option>
    <?php $sqlmake = odbc_exec($cnn, "SELECT DISTINCT Manufacturer FROM lkup.alldata ORDER BY Manufacturer ");
            while($manurs = odbc_fetch_array($sqlmake)) {                                                                        
                echo '<option value="'. $manurs['Manufacturer'] .'">'. $manurs['Manufacturer'] .'</option>';
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

From the above I've been working on this below, which returns no errors but also when you click on the SELECT returns no values in the SELECT.

Where have I gone astray?

My SELECT

```
<select class="select2_category form-control" data-placeholder="Choose a Category" tabindex="1" id="model" name="model">
<option value=""></option>                                                                
</select>
<script>
$(function() {
    $('.make').change(function() {
    var select = $('.model').empty();
        $.get('assets/configs/script.php', {model: $(this).val()}, function(result) {
            $.each(result, function(i, item) {
                $('<option value="' + item.value + '">' + item.name + '</option>').
                    appendTo(select);
            });
        });
    });
    });
   </script>
```

The script.php

```
<?php
session_start();
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London");
error_reporting(0);    

include 'config.php'; //my db settings

if (isset($_GET['model'])) {      
    $model = addslashes($_GET['model']);
    $sqlmodel = odbc_exec($cnn, "SELECT DISTINCT ModelName FROM lkup.MyTable WHERE ModelName IS NOT NULL AND Make = $model ORDER BY ModelName ");
    $modelrs = array();
    while ($row = $sqlmodel->fetch_assoc()) {
        $modelrs[] = array(
            'ModelName' => $modelrs['ModelName']
        );
    }
    echo json_encode($modelrs);
}?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with javascript or jQuery you could run another php echo statement to create the other select options with all the possibilities, and then with jQuery hide or show the appropriate options.

```
    $('select[name=first_select]').on('change', function(){
    var make = $(this).val();
        $.each($('select[name=second_select] option'), function(){
          if($(this).prop('class') != make){
            $(this).hide();
          }
      }
    });
```

Comment: I thought of posting the $_GET['make']; and echo that variable i get, but it didnt return anything, I then thought about posting it into a jquery, but how do I output the jquery as a variable?

Comment: Are you asking how to read a PHP variable in jQuery? If so, like so:    var example = "<?php echo my_php_variable ?>";

Comment: Create your option 2 select box with PHP and give each option the class $manurs['Manufacturer']. You can then use jQuery by doing a change event on the first select. In the change event do an if statement, like if the selected value equals "Audi". You can hide the options in the second select by comparing each options class with the selected value of the first select. Make sense?

Comment: not sure I fully understand, currently I have the same setup as above to pull all model names, the echo shows echo '<option value="'. $modelrs['ModelName'] .'">'. $modelrs['ModelName'] .'</option>'; So your saying use the same echo as in the SELECT 1 echo '<option value="'. $manurs['Manufacturer'] .'">'. $manurs['Manufacturer'] .'</option>';? how do we change it as a function in jquery?

Comment: I've edited the first post with my latest changes, but still going astray, why would this be?

Comment: I have edited my answer to include the jQuery you would need to make this work. Forget what you did in the second script and make your second select the same way you did the first. Give each option in the second select a class of the first select options value.

Comment: Thanks will do, so in your script where you have written if(make == 'Audi') I need to make this the name of the field in the database for Audi?

Comment: If you have only a few makes, and these won't change you can simply hard code the make and do an if statement for each make.

Comment: No I have about 150 makes

Comment: Nothing's ever easy :) Have to do this dynamically then. In addition to what I have you doing, create an array of all the makes in your PHP while loop. You can then iterate through the array within the jQuery loop.

Comment: P.S Should you get this working please make sure to give me an up vote!

Comment: So use something like this `$modelrs = array();
    while ($row = $sqlmodel->fetch_assoc()) {
        $modelrs[] = array(
            'ModelName' => $modelrs['ModelName']
        );` inside thejquery of pull it from a different page? And yes I'll make and tick to say thanks for the help :-)

Comment: I modified my code above...basically I excluded the "Audi" portion. This loop will run every time the user makes a selection on the first select. When that happens the $.each loop looks at the class of every option in the second select and compares the selected value from the first select. If the selected value does not match the class of the second selects option, then it will hide that option.

Comment: I put it in my code, it looks like it was missing a ); I put one in and tested, when I selected the Make, there was nothing in the Model SELECT, when I just used your code, it just shows all the makes regardless of the Make selected.

Comment: I put this into the scripts at the bottom of the page `<script>
        $('select[name=make]').on('change', function () {
            var make = $(this).val();
            $.each($('select[name=model] option'), function () {
                if ($(this).prop('class') != make) {
                    $(this).hide();
                }
            }
        });
    </script>`

Comment: `<select class="select2 form-control" tabindex="1" id="model" name="model">
    <option value=""></option>
    <?php $sqlmodel = odbc_exec($cnn, "SELECT DISTINCT ModelName FROM lkup.MyTable WHERE ModelName IS NOT NULL ORDER BY ModelName ");
        while($modelrs = odbc_fetch_array($sqlmodel)) {                                                                        
            echo '<option value="'. $modelrs['ModelName'] .'">'. $modelrs['ModelName'] .'</option>';
        }
    ?>                                                                                   
</select>`

Comment: nFinIt_loop from your code to my code can you see where I've gone astray?

Comment: Try changing this: $.each($('select[name=model] option') to this: $.each($('select[name=model] > option')

Comment: I made the change and it still shows all models in the list and not just those that are linked to the ones that are selected in the Make SELECT. I don't see where the jquery code filters the Model sql?

Comment: Thanks nFinlt_loop for your help, I found something else that I've used and has worked.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of problems with this I found this link that worked a treat. I think my main problem is that I'm using PHP & MS SQL Server, which makes life difficult.

[This I found as my solution](http://www.yourinspirationweb.com/en/how-to-create-chained-select-with-php-and-jquery/)